# TypeError: ... is not a constructor when requiring class from Mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, require

In a trivial project, I have the following files:

```
app/taxCalculator.js
test/taxCalculator.js
```

In `app/taxCalculator.js` there's a class definition that starts thus:

```
class TaxCalculation {
  constructor(grossSalary, grossDividends) {
    this.grossSalary = grossSalary;
    this.grossDividends = grossDividends;
  }

  // More stuff
}

module.exports = TaxCalculation
```

In `test/taxCalculator.js` there's a Mocha test in which I'm trying to `require()` the class, and instantiate it:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect
const TaxCalculation = require("../app/taxCalculator")
// Some time later
foo = new TaxCalculation(12570,0)
```

When these tests execute, I get the error `TypeError: TaxCalculation is not a constructor` thrown from the line that's attempting instantiation. When running a debugger, I can see that the `const TaxCalculation` in the test is a `Class`.

I'm not a JavaScript programmer (can you tell?) and I'm not quite sure how constructor magic works here. All I want to do is define a class in one file, and instantiate it in another :)

Comment: Can you provide a  GitHub repo or a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using https://codesandbox.io/? Can't reproduce your issue.